# How I do an animation that works with a set timer in python?

Tags: python, animation, timer, tkinter

I am trying to do some animation that works with the timer. When the time finishes, the animation should finish at the same time. I was thinking on doing something like a battery bar in a cell phone. That's why I have a green rectangle in another window, but I don't know how to do for the green get black or the rectangle empty slowly with the timer. If you have another suggestion for animation you can do it. Thanks

---

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import time

aux=False
segundo=60

Ventana1 = Tk()
Ventana1.title("Timer")
Ventana1.geometry("500x350+100+100")

def paso():
    global aux
    global segundo

    if aux:
        segundo -= 1
        tiempo["text"] = segundo
        tiempo.after(1000, paso)

    if segundo==0:
       aux=False
       tiempo.configure(text=segundo, fg="blue")

    if segundo<21:
       tiempo.configure(text=segundo, fg="red")

def inicio ():
    global aux
    global segundo

    segundo=segundo
    if aux:
        pass

    else:
        aux=True
        paso()
        tiempo.configure(text=segundo, fg="blue")

def pausa ():
    global aux, segundo

    aux=False
    tiempo.configure(text=segundo, fg="blue")

def reset ():
    global aux
    global segundo

    segundo=int(Entry.get(Segunditos)) + 60*int(Entry.get(Minuticos))
    aux=False
    tiempo["text"] = segundo
    tiempo.configure(text=segundo, fg="blue")

tiempo = Label(Ventana1, text=segundo, font=("calibri", 200))
tiempo.pack()

Button(Ventana1, text="Arranquelo", command= inicio).place(x=120, y=220)#Button start
Button(Ventana1, text= "Parelo", command= pausa).place(x=200, y=220)#button pause
Button(Ventana1, text= "Acabelo", command= reset).place(x=300, y=220)#button reset

MinAviso=Label(Ventana1, text="Minutos").place(x=125, y=260)
SegAviso=Label(Ventana1, text="Segundos").place(x=305, y=260)

Minuticos=Entry(Ventana1)
Minuticos.place(x=70, y=290)

Segunditos=Entry(Ventana1)
Segunditos.place(x=250, y=290)

from tkinter import *

Ventana2 = Tk()

Canvas = Canvas(Ventana2, width=2000, height=1500)
Canvas.pack()
Canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 1000, 300, fill="green")

mainloop()

#Ventana1.mainloop()
```

Comment: you're not getting errors with `from tkinter import *`

Comment: so I got your code working... Can you explain what you want to happen

Comment: I want that the rectangle works as a progress bar with the timer. When the time is reducing the color in the the rectangle also reduces until zero

Comment: are you aware that tkinter has a progressbar widget (in the ttk package)?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you are creating two instances of `Tk`. Tkinter isn't designed to work that way. If you want a floating window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Next, you need to save a reference to the rectangle you are drawing on the canvas.

```
Canvas = Canvas(Ventana2, ...)
rect = Canvas.create_rectangle(...)
```

As your timer runs, you can modify the object using that reference.

```
def paso():
    ...
    if aux:
        ...
        Canvas.itemconfigure(rect, ...)
```